# Docker for mac does not pull any image

Tags: macos, docker, pull

I have a problem with docker on my mac, maybe someone can help me with this.

My docker was working fine, but after try to download the image jhipster/jhipster-registry:v2.3.0 docker never pull any image again, always when I try to do a pull of any image (ex. docker pull mongo), Console show me the next message:

```
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/library/mongo
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/mongo
```

Maybe someone know what could I do for solve this issue.

Next the info about my environment (If you need some additional info, please tell me).

[Docker version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZHzz.png)

[Mac version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpIYh.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try: `docker pull mongo:latest`

Comment: I got the same message "Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/mongo".

Comment: would you show us `docker info`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody that is here for a similar error, I have to tell you, in my case, this problem is not a Docker problem, yesterday I was in a house's friend and docker works fine, but in my house not, so, this is a problem with my **internet provider**, thank all that try to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify if you are logged in into docker-hub using

`docker login`

if not, do so ( you need to register at https://hub.docker.com/). Docker-Hub recently introduced API-Rate limits partially denying pulls of images for anon-users.

`docker pull mongo` is the same as `docker pull mongo:latest` .. but which image are you actually trying to pull `docker pull library/mongo`? there is no such image on hub.docker.io

Comment: `docker login` is not required for public images. I can do `docker pull mongo` just fine, without logging in anywhere.

Comment: Normally I don't need be logged to pull an image, but I do the login, try again and got the same error. The image that I am trying to download is mongo, I did "docker pull mongo" and got that error, but not is only with mongo, if I do "docker pull mysql" I got the same error.